# Where is the subject in 'love is great'?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subject-verb-agreement, subjects

Is love the subject here? I don't understand it because of verb to be.

Comment: Yes -- this is the noun *love*, not the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Love is the subject: the same when you say "give love" or "all you need is love".
Many feelings have this double quality of being an abstract thing and the action of expressing the feeling.

Comment: if you wanna verbed it you can youst say "to love is great" (it mean expressing your love to a target is great) or "being love is great" (the oposite) etc.

Comment: +1 For the Answer; your Comment is to my mind dubious: *to love* is not the same thing as the noun *love*, and I think you mean *being loved*, not *being love*.

Comment: If you say "give love" (which I've never heard used on its own but perhaps you mean "give love" as in "give my love to Jane" or "she gave him lots of love") then "love" is an object, not a subject.  Perhaps you weren't using the word "suject" in its grammatical sense, but there's potential for confusion here.

Comment: Yes, you are right: it would be being loved, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is, "yes."

In any simple "to be" sentence, the subject is always to the left of "to be."

> I will go. (subject: I)
>
> You are wonderful! (subject: you)
>
> That is amazing! (subject: that)
>
> It was over there.  (subject: it)

Only when you get to more complex sentences will you find the subject to the right.  Questions are good examples:

> How is that possible? (subject: that)
>
> Where has the time gone? (subject: time)
>
> Who was that man? (subject: man)

Comment: Or if you speak Yoda. "Surprised you are." Or more seriously, poetry and song lyrics often vary word order. For example, there's a song titled, "Great is Our God". The subject is "God".

Comment: @Jay, you're correct.  Poetic English is, in fact, entirely grammatically correct.  However, Yoda's statment conforms to my answer.  The subject is to the left ("you").  It's different in that the predicate is to the left, too.  Good catch!  Thanks!

Comment: Good point: The subject is still left of the verb. I was, of course, thinking not left of the predicate adjective.